# Apex - Interactive Report - Hide Column in CSV Download?

Tags: oracle-apex

I've got an interactive report in Apex with some columns.
The user has the option to download the report as CSV file with the standard functionality.

Is there a way to hide a column in the export but display it on the screen.

(Background: one column is a custom link  that should not be exported into the CSV)

Thank you !
Paul

Answer (score 13):

You can hide it by putting a condition on the column of type PL/SQL Expression and using the following as the expression:

```
NVL(:REQUEST,'EMPTY') NOT IN('CSV','XLS','PDF','XML','RTF','HTMLD')
```

That will check the APEX bind variable "REQUEST", and if it is CSV, XLS, PDF, XML, RTF or HTML then the column will not be shown!

**More info**

To stop a column from showing up for an email, you can use the following:

```
NVL(wwv_flow.g_widget_action, 'EMPTY') != 'SEND_EMAIL'
```

Comment: As of 19.2, these request values are appearing as IR[R47011529768140720]_HTMLD, IR[R47011529768140720]_CSV - so perhaps these should now be LIKE statements?

Answer (score 4):

This one did not work for me:

`NVL(:REQUEST,'EMPTY') NOT IN('CSV','XLS','PDF','XML','RTF','HTMLD')`

So another workaround could be the following:

`instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'XLS') = 0 and instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'PDF') = 0 and instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'HTMLD') = 0`

Same logic applies for csv, rtf, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The most upvoted answer didn't work for me.

The workaround from @George worked for me as well:

```
instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'XLS') = 0 and
instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'CSV') = 0
```

I applied this at an Interactive Report column (APEX 21.2)

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 columns.

For the column with URL the Server-side plsql expression should read:

```sql
instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'XLS') = 0 and instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'CSV') = 0 
and
instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'HTML') = 0 and instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'PDF') = 0
```

For the column WITHOUT the URL the Server-side plsql expression should read:

```sql
not(instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'XLS') = 0 and instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'CSV') = 0 
and
instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'HTML') = 0 and instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'PDF') = 0)
```